# Covariance Matrix calculation for eigenfaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently reading the paper about [eigenfaces](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~mturk/Papers/mturk-CVPR91.pdf).
Sadly I can't follow the first step to calculation the eigenfaces.

\begin{align}
 C & = \frac{1}{M}\sum_{n=1}^{M}{\Phi_n\Phi_n^T} =AA^T
\end{align}
Where $\Phi_i = \Gamma_i -\Psi$ and $\Gamma_i$ is one image rearranged into one vector
and $\Psi$ is the average of all images and
$A = [ \Phi_0,\Phi_1,...,\Phi_M]$

Can someone explain the intermediate steps to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error both in the paper and in your rendition of it. In the paper it says $A = [ \Phi_1,...,\Phi_M]$; there's no $\Phi_0$. And the factor $1/M$ is missing in the paper on the right-hand side. So the correct equation is

$$C=\frac1M\sum_{n=1}^M\Phi_n\Phi_n^T =\frac1MAA^T\;.$$

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: But will the part $1/M$ contribute any information other than a scaling factor. Just for knowing, since I am a beginner. I have seen many works on PCA directly starting from $\bf{AA^T}$.